# Did validators reject my parachain candidate or not recieve it at all?

Tags: parachain-collator, rococo-local, inclusion

I'm running a local network based on rococo-local with two relay chain validators and a single collator on parachain 2000. I've set up the network according to the tutorial [Part 1 relay chain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/) and [Part 2 parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/).

Almost everything is normal. The relay chain is live, the registration succeeds, and the collator starts authoring at the correct time. However, the collator just authors sibling blocks at height 1 repeatedly. It never gets a new best and there is no evidence that the relay chain validators have seen the parachain blocks.

**How can I diagnose whether the validators have seen the block at all?**